# Agregar datos a un arraylist desde JOptionPane y guardarlos

Tags: java, array, arraylist

La idea es pedir datos por el `JOptionPane` pero que se vayan guardando para después mostrarlos en pantalla.

```
int cantDatos;
cantDatos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("digite cantidad de paradas"));

ArrayList Arreglo = new ArrayList();
        Arreglo.add(cantDatos);

//aqui quiero meter un ciclo que luego me muestre los datos en pantalla
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

´´´

```
int cantDatos;
cantDatos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("digite cantidad de paradas"));

ArrayList Arreglo = new ArrayList();

//con este bucle pides los datos al usuario y los guardas en el arreglo
for(int i = 1 ; i <= cantDatos ; i ++) {
    Arreglo.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("introduzca el dato Nº " + i)));
}

//con este bucle recorres el arreglo imprimiendo sus datos en consola
for(int i = 0 ; i < Arreglo.size() ; i ++) {
    System.out.println(Arreglo.get(i));
}
```

´´´

Atencion: con este codigo puede salir una excepcion si el usuario introduce un dato no numerico en el JOptionPane, puedes guardar el resultado del JOptionPane en un string y convertirlo dentro de un bloque try-catch antes de meterlo al arreglo para manejar dicha excepcion, pero eso ya no responde a la pregunta.
Ademas de otros problemas que no van al caso

El codigo es para que te hagas a la idea de como recoger y guardar los datos

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, estaba buscando como añadir datos para poder seguir con mi codigo, muchas gracias.